# How to get pretty URL in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url

I have a product controller (Codeigniter) where I load 40 categories in my index function. When I click on a category, I want to load all item of that particular category. To do that, I can easily write a function to load all that items.

```
Function load_item($categoryId’)
{
 // in short    
 …… where categoryId = ‘$categoryId’
 // then load it to view 
}
```

Then I have URL like /product/load_item. But I want URL like /product/laptop or /product/desktop (/product/category_name). So, it's not possible to write 40s function for every category and also its not optimal solution. I don’t want to change anything in index function. Have you any idea please???

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the routes for the url's so under your config folder go to routes and then create a route like so

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';
```

You can find all relevant information in the Codeiginter User Guide

Comment: I cant do it , Because I have other functions in this controller too.

Comment: you can still map it to a function a example would be $route['laptops'] = 'controller/funtion';

Comment: what do u mean by $route['laptop'] ?

Comment: I mean , U tell me to write a route for other functions ??

Comment: You could do that yes

Answer (score 0):

**Method 01**

In `routes.php`

```
$route['category/(:any)'] = 'category/load_item';
```

> Output - `www.example.com/category/(value/number-of-category)`

---

**Method 02**

***In View*** URL passing method(Means `<a>`)

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>category/item/<?php echo category_code?>/<?php echo category_code?>">Click me</a>
```

so ***in controller***

```
Function item($catgoryName, $categoryId)
{
   // in short    
   where categoryId = '$categoryId';
   // then load it to view 
}
```

> Output - `www.example.com/category/item/laptops/1`